# TYPO3 Extension - Redirect to another page in show action if no record is set or not available

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-8.x, typo3-extensions

How can I redirect to another page when someone access the detail page but without a record or if record is not available?

I have detail records like

```
domain.com/abc/ABC1234
```

When somone enters

```
domain.com/abc/
```

... I get:

```
Uncaught TYPO3 Exception
#1298012500: Required argument "record" is not set for Vendor\Extension\Controller\ActionController->show. (More information)

TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Controller\Exception\RequiredArgumentMissingException thrown in file
/is/htdocs/www/typo3_src-8.7.11/typo3/sysext/extbase/Classes/Mvc/Controller/AbstractController.php in line 425.
```

... in this case I want it to redirect to:

```
domain.com/other-page/
```

... I also need it if a specific record is not available.
... how to do so?

```
/**
 * action show
 *
 * @param \Action $record
 * @return void
 */
public function showAction(Action $record) {

    $this->view->assign('record', $record);

}
```

Here are some examples [TYPO3 Extbase - redirect to pid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40551408/typo3-extbase-redirect-to-pid) ... but not sure how to implement it

Edit: What works is ...

```
/**
 * action show
 *
 * @param \Action $record
 * @return void
 */
public function showAction(Action $record=null) {   

  if ($record === null) { 
    $pageUid = 75;
    $uriBuilder = $this->uriBuilder;
    $uri = $uriBuilder
      ->setTargetPageUid($pageUid)
      ->build();
    $this->redirectToUri($uri, 0, 404);
  } else {
    $this->view->assign('record', $record);

  }

}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TYPO3 Extbase - redirect to pid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40551408/typo3-extbase-redirect-to-pid)

Comment: Can you undefine the duplicate? ... I redefined my requirements ... please see above

Comment: I still think it is a duplicate since the proper way to perform a redirect is mentioned in that other post. Contrary to the suggestions below you should not use `redirect()` but `redirectToUri()` instead.

Comment: I also tried $uriBuilder = $this->uriBuilder; $uri = $uriBuilder ->setTargetPageUid(75) ->build(); $this->redirectToUri($uri, 0, 404); in the show action if ($record === null) but can't get it work

Comment: You should add this to your question and also what exactly happened, especially errors or similar.

Comment: In general I agree ... but since its embedded in the if ($record === null) condition I would say my use case is slightly different ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `redirect` method needs an action and controller parameter. So your redirect code is wrong.

```
$this->redirect($actionName, $controllerName = NULL, $extensionName = NULL, array $arguments = NULL, $pageUid = NULL, $delay = 0, $statusCode = 303);
```

To redirect to an PageUID you need to use the uriBuilder and the `redirectToUri` method. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40551408/typo3-extbase-redirect-to-pid/40551878#40551878) for an example.

Comment: this returns me Uncaught TYPO3 Exception syntax error, unexpected '$arguments' (T_VARIABLE), expecting '(' ... when I access a detail page

Comment: the code in this post shows the syntax of `->redirect` to show you that you use it wrong. But you should click on the link under "here" to see how you should do it in an other way, because `->redirect` dont support redirect to an PageUID.

Comment: I see. Yes, thanks to your solution in the other post it works.

Answer (score 1):

This should do the trick:

```
public function showAction(Action $record=null) {
  if ($record === null) { 
    $this->redirect(/* add parameters as needed */); 
  } else {
    // other code
  }
```

Alternative Solution (from Simon Oberländer)

```
public function intializeShowAction() {
  if (!$this->request->hasArgument('record')) {
    $this->redirect(/* add parameters as needed */); // stops further execution
  }
}
```

Your question suggests that there should be an other action without arguments, probably a listAction, that is the DEFAULT action. The default action gets called when no action is specified. It is the first action enlisted in the ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin() call.

```
\TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ExtensionUtility::configurePlugin(
    'Vendor.' . $_EXTKEY,
    'Pluginname',
    array(
        'Domainobject' => 'list, show',
    ),
    // non-cacheable actions
    array(
        'Domainobject' => 'list, show',
    )
);
```

Regarding > The identity property "TTTT" is no UID

You have to distinguish between no parameter and an invalid parameter. For the latter you can add @ignorevalidation to the showAction comments and do your validation testing within the action - or you can leave it to extbase that displays the error message you have seen.
Where would you get a link like domain.com/abc/TTTT/ from anyhow? Unless the link is expired.

BTW: in a production system you would disable the display of exceptions, thus the display of the website would work.

Comment: ... I tried the $record === null approach but unfortunately got errors again. Please see my edit above

Comment: ... yes ... I do have both list & show action defined as you suggested

Comment: 'Where would you get a link like domain.com/abc/TTTT/ from anyhow?' ... when somebody wants to type in the url the globally known record ID (which I defined a speaking url with realurl) ... the detail page of this record should be accesses ...

Comment: ... but of course ... if not available it should be redirected

Comment: `somebody wants to type in the url the globally known record ID`

This is not a real usecase, this is a hack. Or do you want your visitors to type the full URL including the record title? Usually someone clicks on a link - a link that you provide.

Answer (score -1):

This could be a solution:

```
/**
 * Show a booking object
 *
 * @return void
 * @throws \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Exception\NoSuchArgumentException
 */

```
public function showAction()
{
    $bookingObject = null;
    $bookingObjectUid = 0;
    if ($this->request->hasArgument('bookingObject')) {
        $bookingObjectUid = (int)$this->request->getArgument('bookingObject');
    }
    if ($bookingObjectUid > 0) {
        $bookingObject = $this->bookingObjectRepository->findByIdentifier($bookingObjectUid);
    }
    if (!($bookingObject instanceof BookingObject)) {
        $messageBody = 'Booking object can\'t be displayed.';
        $messageTitle = 'Error';
        $this->addFlashMessage($messageBody, $messageTitle, AbstractMessage::ERROR);
        $this->redirect('list');
    }
    $this->view->assign('bookingObject', $bookingObject);
}
```

```

Comment: I think this is way to complicated for such a simple requirement.